# how to set left and right textview and radio button in constraint layout?

Tags: android

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:letterSpacing="0.01"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="32sp"
        android:text="+44 2079460860"
        android:textColor="@color/colorDusk"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="32sp"
        android:text="Mobile UK"
        android:textColor="@color/secondryColor"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone_number" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_button_background"
        android:button="@null"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.864"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phone_number"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my RecyclerView:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />
```

This is my layout i am unable to set left or start both text view and right or end side  radio button inside constraint layout my current screen is below :

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

while i want check box full right side or end  of constraint layout please suggest me ho to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Updated

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:letterSpacing="0.01"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="32sp"
            android:text="+44 2079460860"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/radio_button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="Mobile UK"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/radio_button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone_number" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @IZM i am not able to set Radio-button  right side still ...not coming.

Comment: i am displaying this recyclerview in dialog

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, change `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` to `LinearLayout` and set layout `weight`.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:letterSpacing="0.01"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="32sp"
            android:text="+44 2079460860"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="32sp"
            android:text="Mobile UK"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            />



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="right"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:button="@null"
            />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

or, you can use below sample code :

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mobile UK"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+44 2079460860"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i am not able to set Radio-button right side still ...not coming.

Comment: i updated my code @SudhaKumari sure, it will work for you

Comment: NO dear still this code is not working its coming touch with textview

Comment: Are you using Dialog @SudhaKumari, its AlertDialog or CustomDialog ?

Comment: Dialog Class if u want i can share u cod https://paste.ofcode.org/XzYWnJXF4LAPvZiy6pkD3i  check this @Abhishek kumar

Comment: Can you check one time your recycler_row parent layout change LinearLayout to RelativeLayout

Comment: Share your dialog_travel_number.xml  layout @SudhaKumari

Comment: its there i have paste in given link below check that @Abhishek kumar

Comment: Have you used DataBinding in your project @SudhaKumari

Comment: even i have change it to relative layout then radio button is not showing

Comment: yes i have use Data binding in project @Abhishek kumar

Comment: i will solve this issue any how , but my suggestion is do not use that, some time it creates lotz of problem. @SudhaKumari

Comment: i have updated code of dialog try one time,@SudhaKumari

Comment: i checked problem is only with your Recycler_row layout, i updated my answer check and reply @SudhaKumari

Comment: still same issue wait i ll show u screen @Abhishek kumar

Comment: Second LinearLayout change to  android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: Please compare with your previous one, i'm sure it will work for you.@SudhaKumari

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/H6QhbDT.png check this and can u give me updated xml @Abhishek kumar

Comment: same thing i given wrap_content

Comment: Its seems like this, Could i give you my own code to achieve the same @SudhaKumari